# How to allow empty fields(not required field) in AJAX Bootstrap form validation?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using Bootstrap form validation and I'm trying to figure out how to ignore empty field or not required field when submitting the form.

**The Form**

```
<form id="contactForm" name="sentMessage" novalidate="novalidate">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                   <div class="form-group">
                    <select class="form-control" id="prefix" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Please choose Prefix.">
                      <option>Mr.</option>
                      <option>Ms.</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Full Name *" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your Full Name.">
                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" id="position" type="text" placeholder="Company Position *" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your Company Position.">
                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" id="company" type="text" placeholder="Company Name *" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your Company Name.">
                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" id="company_address" type="text" placeholder="Company Address *" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your Company Address.">
                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" id="zip_code" type="text" placeholder="Zip Code *" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your Zip Code.">
                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" id="phone" type="tel" placeholder="Phone Number *" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your Phone Number.">
                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" id="fax" type="tel" placeholder="Fax Number">
                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" id="mobile" type="text" placeholder="Mobile Number *" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your Mobile Number.">
                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" id="email" type="email" placeholder="Your Email *" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your Email Address.">
                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" id="website" type="text" placeholder="Website *" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your Website.">
                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="message" placeholder="Comments" data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                  </div>
                   <div class="form-group form-check">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="subscribe" checked>
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">This enables me to receive updates and invitations <br>from Fiera de Manila, Inc.</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                  <div id="success"></div>
                  <button id="sendMessageButton" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl text-uppercase" type="submit">Register</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
```

The Fax number field is not required and I want it to be accepted by AJAX even if it's empty when submitting the form.

Or is there any other way to resolve this issue?

**AJAX**

```
    $(function() {

      $("#contactForm input,#contactForm textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
        preventSubmit: true,
        submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
          // additional error messages or events
        },
        submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
          event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
          // get values from FORM
          var prefix = $("select#prefix").val();
          var name = $("input#name").val();
          var position = $("input#position").val();
          var company = $("input#company").val();
          var company_address = $("input#company_address").val();
          var zip_code = $("input#zip_code").val();
          var phone = $("input#phone").val();
          var fax = $("input#fax").val();
          var mobile = $("input#mobile").val();
          var email = $("input#email").val();
          var website = $("input#website").val();
          var message = $("textarea#message").val();
          var subscribe = $("input#subscribe").val();
          var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
          // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
          if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
            firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
          }
          $this = $("#sendMessageButton");
          $this.prop("disabled", true); // Disable submit button until AJAX call is complete to prevent duplicate messages
          $.ajax({
            url: "././mail/contact_me.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
              prefix: prefix,
              name: name,
              position: position,
              company: company,
              company_address: company_address,
              zip_code: zip_code,
              phone: phone,
              fax: fax,
              mobile: mobile,
              email: email,
              website: website,
              message: message,
              subscribe: subscribe,
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function() {
              // Success message
              $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
              $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                .append("</button>");
              $('#success > .alert-success')
                .append("<strong>Your message has been sent. </strong>");
              $('#success > .alert-success')
                .append('</div>');
              //clear all fields
              $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
            },
            error: function() {
              // Fail message
              $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
              $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                .append("</button>");
              $('#success > .alert-danger').append($("<strong>").text("Sorry " + firstName + ", it seems that my mail server is not responding. Please try again later!"));
              $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
              //clear all fields
              $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
            },
            complete: function() {
              setTimeout(function() {
                $this.prop("disabled", false); // Re-enable submit button when AJAX call is complete
              }, 1000);
            }
          });
        },
        filter: function() {
          return $(this).is(":visible");
        },
      });

      $("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab("show");
      });
    });

    /*When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes */
    $('#name').focus(function() {
      $('#success').html('');
    });
```

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand what's the problem. You should provide the expected and actual results to see what you want to do. You ask how to set a nullable field in the form, but then you provide your own answer (which is working if I understand), so what's the problem?

Comment: @DavidGildour it's working only for required fields but what if I wan't it not required for specific field like Fax Number? how can I do that in AJAX?

Comment: I want the form submission to allow not required field.

Comment: @JoffTornea Your statement "Fax Number field is empty, the form submission still continue and will be successfully submitted." you remove required then will submit the form when clicked on submit. If you prevent on empty just check ur js code

Comment: @AnkitPandey Thank you. I have already found a solution.